# type character not supported

Tags: r, dataframe, median

I was trying to run a median test using R, according to instructions from the following website: https://www.statology.org/moods-median-test-r/

when I ran the code

```
   library(coin)
   library(NLP)
   data21=read_excel("file name")
   dat21=data.frame(data21)
   colnames(dat21)=c("identity", "ratio")
   median_test(identity~ratio, data=dat21)
```

the output returns Error in xtrafo(object@x) : data class “character” is not supported.

Here is a screen shot of a part of my dataset.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZDcF.png)

The first column of my current dataframe is a list of strings and the second column numerics (As the website instructed)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Check whether `dat21$ratio` is indeed numeric (the error warning says different). You can use `is.numeric(dat21$ratio)` or query the mode with `mode(dat21$ratio)`.

Comment: I just ran the code you've provided; the output is TRUE. So I think that is not where the problem is at.

Comment: would be easier if you showed the actual code you used (which clearly isnt whats on that site as you seem to have different data)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's possible that `median_test` requires that your independent variable be a `factor` type instead of a `character` type. Does `is.factor()` on your independent variable return `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: Please expand your answer to include all the relevant information that will enable us to make at least an educated guess.

Comment: @David it's False. I tried to use as.factor to convert each variable to factor, but it returns this error   

> dat21["Mutant",]=as.factor(dat21["Mutant",])
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames

Comment: @Andrew That isn't quite the correct syntax. I think what you want is something like `dat21$identity.factor <- as.factor(dat21$identity)`, assuming that `dat21$identity` is your independent variable. R will automatically convert your unique levels into a factor variable. Then you would use  `median_test(identity.factor~ratio, data=dat21)`.